# Parametric equation for a space curve

Tags: curves, parametrization

With reference to the following image:

[image]

the blue curve has trivially a parametrization:

$$(x, y, z) = (\cos\theta, \, \sin\theta, \, 0) \; \; \; \text{with} \; \theta \in [0,\,2\pi)$$

I would like to determine the parametric equations of the red curve, very badly drawn in Paint, where I mean a sinusoidal curve along the blue circumference.

Although I thought about it a lot, I still couldn't figure out how to derive these parametric equation. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a curve of the form
$$
r(\theta) = r_0 + A \cos{(\omega \theta )}
$$
But it's not very clear what you mean with the hand-drawn curve. Is it supposed to come out of the $z=0$-plane?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try$$\theta\mapsto\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\frac{\cos(8\theta)}8\right),$$for instance.

[image]

Comment: The $z$ coordinate had to be a waving line again, and so I thought about $\cos(8\theta)$, but then the waves would go too high and too low. That's why I divided by $8$.

Comment: No need for that. Just consider:$$\theta\mapsto\left(\cos\theta+\frac{\cos(8\theta)}8,\sin\theta,0\right).$$

Comment: @TeM If you want the red curve in the Z=0 plane, then you probably want to oscillate in the direction of the unit normal vector rather than in the x direction. Here's a comparison: https://www.math3d.org/cCvATTaY